# How to introduce my setup to the players?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques

For quite a while, I've been GM-ing some Pathfinder games for me and a bunch of friends. Usually I try to prepare as much as I can, making my NPCs, major plot-point, the list goes on.

But even though I'm more often than not quite prepared to run a campaign, I always run into several problems, one of those would be this: I have no idea how I should introduce my world to my players. What information should I give them, what is relevant, what is not, and, most of all, what is interesting?

I usually go with this approach: I start with the city they start in, I tell them if it's a village, a small town, a city, or whatever. After that I talk a little bit about the country, mostly: the religion(s) practiced the most, if it's a rich country, or a poor one, and if there is any details of note (exemple : if the country is at war with their neighboor).

**My question would be this:** Am I giving my players enough (or too much) information?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Did you ask your players if they like the way you do this? Some people like to listen to some worldbuilding elements - others are there to kill Goblins. There are lots of different playstyles. What works for my group (*small city, recently  overrun by Goblins - go rescue villagers*) might or might not work for your group. How long does your introduction take? Is it part of your *Session 0*? Do you prefer one big outline in the beginning or small bits every now and then? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I create a document that contains all the info someone in their location and background is expected to know without a knowledge roll.  I use to make it a hand out; now it sits in my google docs campaign folder with other campaign info.